# why use seminconductors instead of plain conductors and insulators

Tags: pcb

In a pcb board, why do we se semicon instead of just plain conductors and insulators? What we just need to do is control current in ehich we either pass them or block them

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Semiconductors are used for specific applications (when we want to control voltage/current flow), and so are conductors and insulators.

Comment: What if your car brakes stops the car at spot(immediately) and accelerator accelerates at full speed ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit of a long explanation, but trust me, I do get to addressing your question!

There are three fundamental electronic "behaviors": resistance, capacitance, and inductance.  We have made electronic components where these behaviors are the major purpose of the component.  Of course they are resistors, capacitors, and inductors.

We call these components "passive components" because they are largely passive in that they just "are", they don't actively do anything.  Other passive components are wire and connectors. A passive component is a lot like a fork.  A fork doesn't do anything, it just sits there.  A fork is only useful when it is manipulated by something/someone else.

You can't build very useful circuits using just passive components.  You need an active component!

An active component is something that amplifies a signal, or switches a signal.  In the early days of computers, we used a relay.  If you run electricity through a relay coil, it turns on or off a mechanical switch.  But relays have problems.  They are large.  They consume a lot of power.  They are slow.  They are noisy.  But in theory you could build something like an Intel i7 processor that runs Windows completely out of relays.  It would be painfully slow, it would be beyond huge, and it would use more power than most cities-- but you could do it.

After relays we invented Vacuum tubes.  Initially these were used in the same way that relays were used:  running electricity through one part of the tube caused current to flow (or not flow) through a different part of the tube.  It was like a switch, but worked faster than relays and was somewhat more reliable too.  But vacuum tubes were still large and consumed a lot of power.

Then came in the "semiconductors".  The exact meaning of the term "semiconductor" really isn't important to us, in much the same way that Vacuum isn't important in "Vacuum Tube".  What is important is that these are active components that are able to operate like a switch-- in much the same way as vacuum tubes and relays.  We've learned how to make these semiconductor devices really small, really fast, and in huge quantities.  That's why we prefer to use semiconductors more than tubes and relays!

The point of all this was to give you some background on what exactly a "semiconductor" is.  Well, it's a switch!  A very small and usually very fast switch.

So... Your question was comparing semiconductors to conductors/insulators.  The problem is that they don't really compare.  The terminology might make you think they are comparable, but they are not.  It is a bit like comparing a "light sour cream" with a "light bulb".  Really what you are doing is comparing wire to a switch.  Sometimes you want a wire, and sometimes you want a switch but you never really need to ask yourself "should I use wire, or should I use a switch?"  Just like you don't ask yourself if you should use light sour cream or a light bulb.

But back to the lesson on types of electronic components...  Almost any useful electronic circuit uses a mix of passive and active components.  Only the most basic of circuits will use only one type or another.  Active and passive components are equally important, even though the active components are the ones that get all the glory.

Answer (score -5):

I think the current flow in a conductor is quite difficult to control and switch.Since semiconductors lie between the conductors and the insulators it switches over between the two materials at essentially two different temperatures which makes it more flexible.The current flow is controlled within the desired level.

Comment: I don't think you get what a semiconductor is, do you? What you have described is a thermistor.